# Libxl read integer from excel file

Tags: c++, excel

I am using Libxl for c++ to read from an .xlsx file. The code is as follows

```
void main()
{
    Book* book = xlCreateXMLBook();
    if (book) {
        if(book->load("input.xlsx")) {
            Sheet* sheet = book->getSheet(0);
            if (sheet) {
            long int id; 
            for(int i=1; i<15; i++) {
                id = sheet->readNum(i,0);
                cout << id << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    book->release();
}
```

The excel sheet has the following data and the output seems to be different.

```
Original Data | Output from code
UNKNOWN       | 0
47012         | 141366
48964         | 154840
425214        | 0
47018         | 134427
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would appear that LibXL is a commercial product. Maybe you could rely on their support?

Comment: `void main` is not a legal signature.

Comment: @user62089, Meaning you should use `int main` because your code is not valid C++ as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

readNum returns a double not a long int

I'm assuming "UNKNOWN" is a string. If so you can do this:

```
double id;
const wchar_t* str;
for(int i=1; i<15; i++) {
    str = sheet->readStr(i, 0);
    if (str) {
        wcout << str << endl; // need to use wcout as it's a wide string
    } else {
        id = sheet->readNum(i,0);
        cout << id << endl;
    }
}
```

According to the docs, readStr will return NULL if the cell does not contain a string, so then you can fall back to reading an number.